# Resize png image, no black bg

Tags: image, upload, resize

I've searched and searched on all sides, but I could not find any script that allows to resize images png maintaining transparency. All scripts that I used to recreate the image with a black background.

I focused on this script that is right for me, so I ask kindly to those who will help me how to fix what I ask. Thank you very much indeed.

http://www.9lessons.info/2014/07/ajax-upload-and-resize-image-with-php.html